# Unresolved Maven Depencencies on Sprint Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to get started with Spring, but I cannot even make the getting-started projects work. It seems like I'm having some issue with the configuration, maybe? I installed all the requirements written in the Spring website.

I will upload a screenshot and the error.

> CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1:
>   ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to
>   repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.36.215]
>   failed: Connection timed out: connect

[image: Spring Tool Suite]

Comment: Rebuilding workspace means cleaning the project, is not it? Thank you :)

Comment: By the way: if it is that the meaning, then it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maven repo sometimes have difficulties to respond to download requests.

This usually tells it:

> Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.36.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect

However even the site would be working well by now, this hinders downloading plugin:

> resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

So if [this link](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1/) is working but the error persists delete your local directory containing the plugin:

```
${home}/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1
```

and try again.

You can also try to use the latest `maven-compiler-plugin` by adding:

```
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

Comment: Hi. I tried to delete that folder and then restart STS cleaning the project, but nothing seems to change. Same error.

Comment: Check also that it actually is the same error, for maven-compiler-plugin. It might need deletion of other plugin/dependency dirs also. Sometimes it is easier to delete the whole ~/.m2/repository directory if there are many failing deps.

Comment: Hello @pirho. Thank you for the support. Yes, the direct link works for me. I've deleted the whole repo directory and cleaned the project, but the error persists:

Comment: CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:

Comment: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):

Comment: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.36.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Doesn't it exist a Spring Tool Suite ready to use ( = with all depencencies installed) to avoid this problem?

Comment: @Giovarco No, it is something Maven download when needed. I made a little update on my answer. Can you try that an tell if it generates the same error?

Comment: good day! I got rid of that error, but now I get another one. Now I would like to start the server in debug mode, but I get that "Port 8080 required by Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.2 is already in use". I expect there to start the server and then being able to connect to the end-point of the server (the one of the exercise).